# MongoDB MMS-Agent error message

Tags: mongodb

for my newly installed MongoDB on Ubuntu system, I also install MMS-Agent but the following message show up after run for few mins.

What is the problem?

```
xx@ubuntu12Dev:~/mms-agent$ python agent.py
2012-05-29 22:54:22,319 INFO Starting agent parent process - version: 1.4.1
2012-05-29 22:54:22,320 INFO Started agent parent process - version: 1.4.1
2012-05-29 22:54:27,409 INFO Starting agent process - version 1.4.1
2012-05-29 22:54:27,414 INFO Started agent process - parent pid: 2877 - version: 1.4.1
2012-05-29 22:56:31,391 INFO starting non-blocking stats monitoring: ubuntu12Dev:27017
2012-05-29 22:56:31,393 INFO starting blocking stats monitoring: ubuntu12Dev:27017
2012-05-29 22:56:31,393 INFO starting munin monitoring: ubuntu12Dev:4949
2012-05-29 23:04:37,040 ERROR Problem with upgrade check: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "agent.py", line 190, in run
    res = urllib2.urlopen( self.settings.version_url % { 'key' : self.settings.mms_key } )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError:
```

Comment: Are you still seeing this message?

Comment: yes, seeing it just few mins after running

Comment: what is self.settings.version_url?

Comment: is this what you meant? version_url = mms_server + "/agent/v1/version/%(key)s"   and mms_server = "https://mms.10gen.com"

Comment: can you put code in the agent to catch URLError and print e.code, and print the resulting value of version_url?